# How to add lib (typings) to a single monaco editor?

Tags: javascript, typescript, monaco-editor

I have an editor, like this:

```
editor.create(this._element, {
            language: "javascript",
            minimap: { enabled: false },
            automaticLayout: true,
            readOnly: this.props.readOnly,
        });
```

To define some typings, I can do this:

```
languages.typescript.javascriptDefaults.addExtraLib(...);
```

However, I want to add the lib (typings) to a single editor only (the one above). I.e. I don't want it to be global / default across all editors.

Is it possible? How?

Answer (score 2):

That's not possible. All editor instances use the same background worker, which in turn controls all extra libs. What you probably can do is to switch libs depending on which editor is visible. However, that won't work if you can have multiple editors with different scopes visible at the same time.